# Python grouping items and looping with a step

Tags: python

If I had this list:

```
y =[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

And I want to select `a` and `b`, then `e` and `f`, what's the syntax for that?

I've tried:

```
y = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]
for letter in range(0,len(y),2):
    print(letter)
```

The result I want is

```
[a, b, e, f i,j]
```

But instead I get every second letter:

```
a
c
e
g
i
```

When I've tried using slice notation **print(y[:1])** I only get the first two values in the list.

Comment: If you `import itertools`: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(lst[::4], lst[1::4])))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to use a list comprehension with an if-clause ('filter') that will pick the items in your span that you want.

```
ls = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
ls_spans = [x for i, x in enumerate(ls) if i % 4 in [0,1]]
```

To tease this out more, what we do is a list comprehension:

```
ls_spans = [x for x in ls]  # Essentially just copies the list
```

But we want to select only certain members of a 'span', which we identify as a 4-unit length: (`abcd`, `efgh`,`ij` in our list).

```
ls_spans = [x for x in ls if x_is_wanted()]
```

To do this, since the fact of whether we want `x` or not is dependent on it's position, we use `enumerate` to pair each element in the list with an index (the `i` in the list comprehension below):

```
ls_spans = [x for i, x in enumerate(ls) if x_is_wanted(i)]
```

Now, we consider the function `x_is_wanted` which has to say 'yes' or 'no' (`True` or `False`) for each element:

```
def x_is_wanted(i: int) -> bool:
    span_length = 4
    acceptable_positions = [0, 1]  # Remember we are 0-indexed!
    return i % span_length in acceptable_positions  # We use modulo to get the remainder, which is equivalent to the position in the span.
```

The complete program would probably look like:

```
def x_is_wanted(i: int) -> bool:
    span_length = 4
    acceptable_positions = [0, 1]  # Remember we are 0-indexed!
    return i % span_length in acceptable_positions    

ls_spans = [x for i, x in enumerate(ls) if x_is_wanted(i)]
```

But we can more easily inline this, if we don't need to re-use the function:

```
# Play with these params to see what changes!
span_length = 4
acceptable_positions = [0, 1]
ls = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
ls_spans = [x for i, x in enumerate(ls) if i % span_length in acceptable_positions]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the step to 4. For every 4 items, you need the first two(3 and 4 are skipped). so :

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

new_list = []
for i in range(0, len(lst), 4):
    new_list.append(lst[i])
    new_list.append(lst[i + 1])

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the iterable is really just a string/collection of characters:

```
from textwrap import wrap
from itertools import chain

print(list(chain.from_iterable(wrap("abcdefghij", 2)[::2])))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'i', 'j']
>>>
```

If it's an arbitrary iterable:

```
from itertools import islice, chain

def chunk_wise(iterable, chunk_size):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while chunk := list(islice(it, chunk_size)):
        yield chunk

print(list(chain.from_iterable(islice(chunk_wise("abcdefghij", 2), 0, None, 2))))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'i', 'j']
>>>
```